# Hi I am getting Access denied error when consuming a wcf service

Tags: wcf, console-application

Error:

> Cannot open 'C:\Users\veeru\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WCFProject\HelloServiceHost\obj\Debug\HelloServiceHost.exe'
>   for writing -- 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\veeru\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\WCFProject\HelloServiceHost\obj\Debug\HelloServiceHost.exe'
>   is denied.'

Answer (score 0):

You will get this type of error when you have launched HelloServiceHost.exe directly from output path of VS project and trying to build solution/project while exe instance is still running. Or exe instance is still hanging there in memory because of unknown reason. You can try following steps:

1. Go to Taskmanager and check if you have instance of HelloServiceHost.exe running there and if its then kill it.
2. If answer to step 1 is negative then close your Visual Studio and reopen it.